# Manually change query in Polymer / Plunker

Tags: html, polymer, plunker

I am still very new to coding. To practice coding I've tried to get an API (from the Rijksmuseum) to run. So far, it has worked as you can see over here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jCYxJz?p=preview

```
  <p>You searched for: {{query}}</p>
  <form>
    <label id="label" for="name">Change your query:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <button on-click="{{ myFunction }}" type="submit">Commit changes</button>
  </form>
  <core-ajax 
    url="https://www.rijksmuseum.nl/api/nl/collection?maker={{query}}&ps=30&key=ssCRX6qW&format=json&imgonly=true&s=chronologic&f.dating.period={{period}}" 
    auto 
    response="{{response}}">
  </core-ajax>
```

My question is:

On top of the current page, as you can see in the Plunker, the user is told "you searched for.." and the user is then offered an input field to manually change the search query. Now.. how do I get the field to actually work?

The current search-query is transmitted via the Index.html where I have to type it in as an attribute-value. This is then send to the Rijksmuseum.html file where it is picked up by the polymer-element.

Anyone had any tips on how to get this done?

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign a id to the ajax element call it "ajax". remove the type="submit" from your button that will make your page refresh. change your myFunction to match the 1 below.

```
    myFunction: function() {
      var query = this.$.name.value;
      this.query = query;
      this.$.ajax.go();
    //alert("Thanks for committing!!");
  }
```

also a fork so you can see it work 
http://plnkr.co/edit/jGZpc6jNy6IinBKGB4ip?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! Now that I see what you've done I understand why it works, but I didn't succeed in figuring it out myself before. It has however allowed me to expand upon it, to also make the "period" changeable for users: [http://plnkr.co/edit/kh6vbp8mpQkQhHEQQMpT?p=preview]

Comment: polymer is like that to me. most things that seem complicated are not once i see how it works. just on a side note as far as functionality of the added button. i would do 2 functions 1 for each option that way if say i am looking at 20th century with 1 artist and i only want to change artist not century or centry and not artist i don't have to make 2 request. example http://plnkr.co/edit/5y3TlO6h7ZCPG6uP9QV4?p=preview

Comment: Ah yes, I can see what you've done. Works better, looks nicer. Thnx!

Comment: Hi Jimi. Given your knowledge of Polymer & Plunker, any chance you can help me out with this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473437/call-list-item-by-index-number-in-polymer-function I'm stuck again.. and I can't seem to find the solution myself.